# Hive not launching in PuTTy

Tags: hadoop, hive

Relatively new to Hive/Hadoop. For the past two days, I haven't been able to launch Hive and it's been stuck hanging after I try to start it from PuTTy. It hangs on

> WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
>
> Logging initialized using configuration in
>   file:/etc/hive/2.4.0.0-169/0/hive-log4j.properties

I've tried killing all Yarn Application tasks but that doesn't work. I've tried restarting my Ambari environment. I've tried debugging at Hive Launch but it just goes on forever.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me out or point me in some direction! Thanks

*Screenshot of Ambari dashboard:*

[image: Screenshot of Ambari dashboard.]

*Screenshot of endless debugging at Hive launch:*

[image: Screenshot of endless debugging at Hive launch]

Comment: nodemanager looks down. Start it.

Comment: @ozw1z5rd Thanks for the reply! I'm very new to this. How would I do this?

Comment: I don't know ambari. Node Manager belongs to YARN, try to restart Yarn.